# regex prevent match word

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm using the regex

```
/part\s?[0-9]*\s?:?/g
```

to match words like

"**part 20**" "**part21**" "**part30:**" etc

the problem is that it matchs also the word "part" inside other words like "Re**part**ition"

it should match word only if it is a whole word i.e

```
part 01       -match
part 33:      -match
part          -no match
participial   -no match
```

Comment: Start with `\b`

Comment: Use `\b` on each side of the word.  That's a word break.

Comment: @Thefourthbird `\bpart\b\s?[0-9]*\s?:?` matches `part`

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you want is to make one or more digits mandatory, changing `*` to `+`, and adding \b to ensure the "part" is not the end of a larger word:

```
/\bpart\s?[0-9]+\s?:?/g
```

And if you are actually using the matched string(s), I would think you would only want to include the whitespace after a number if there was a colon too:

```
/\bpart\s?[0-9]+(?:\s?:)?/g
```